# define marker for scatter plot

Tags: matplotlib, scatter-plot

I want to define markers in my plot based on the values in my data.

the code is here

```
data = np.loadtxt("data.txt")
x1 = data[:,3]
y1 = data[:,10]
z = data[:,1]
mf = data[:,0]

n_file=len(x1)
mrk=[None]



fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()                   
fig.set_size_inches(18.5/2, 10.5/2)


for i in range(len(x1)):

        if mf[i] ==1:
            mrk={'o'}
        elif mf[i] ==2:
            mrk={'s'}
        elif mf[i] ==3:
            mrk={'*'}
        elif mf[i] ==4:
            mrk={'+'}
        else: 
            mrk={'x'}

        sc=plt.scatter(x1[i],y1[i], marker=mrk)


plt.show()
```

and it returns:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There does not seem to be any reason to use a set here. Just use strings, i.e. instead of `mrk={'o'}` use `mrk='o'`.

In addition, you may of course use a dictionary to define your mapping, in case the possible values in `mf` are known.

```
mapping = {1 : "o", 2 : "s", 3 : "*", 4 : "+", 5 : "x"}

for i in range(len(x1)):
    sc=plt.scatter(x1[i],y1[i], marker=mapping[mf[i]])
```

**EDIT**:

You actually can get around the `KeyError` problem by either using the `dict.get()` method or by using a `defaultdict`. Below an example that utilises both possibilities with `'.'` as default for the marker:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict

x1 = np.random.random(100)
y1 = np.random.random(100)
mf = np.random.choice(np.arange(10),100)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2)

##using the 'dict.get()' method
mapping1 = {1 : "o", 2 : "s", 3 : "*", 4 : "+", 5 : "x"}
for i in range(len(x1)):
    sc=axes[0].scatter(x1[i],y1[i], marker=mapping1.get(mf[i],'.'))

##using a defaultdict
mapping2=defaultdict(lambda: '.', mapping1)
for i in range(len(x1)):
    sc=axes[1].scatter(x1[i],y1[i], marker=mapping2[mf[i]])

plt.show()
```

The results are indeed identical:

[image: result of the code in the edit]

Comment: Thank you, but it returns :
KeyError: 12.5

Comment: As said *"in case the possible values in mf are known"*. One cannot know if that is the case for you or not. If not, you need to use the first solution here.

Comment: Actually, you could use a `DefaultDict` (or use `dict.get()`) to get around the KeyError problem...

Comment: Of course @ThomasKühn, I somehow forgot about that option completely. I guess you may provide this as answer, or, if you want edit this answer and we make it a community wiki.